# Regex check digit lengths in separated string

Tags: regex, digits, csv

How can I validate a string that separated by commas and I have to check the records lengths one by one.

Example:
1234567890,123456,1234567890,12345

I would like to do a regex that returns all the not correct number lengths (not equals 10)
Where I want to use this pattern don't have any loop or split function so that's why I want to make this with Regex.

Comment: The point is that I would like to have returned all of the numbers which ones not 10 lengths. So this is I why a cant make this by myself because I didn't know how can I analyze the number lengths between the commas one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Regex matches all the numbers not equal by 10, either from the start, after a comma, or at the end of the string.

```
(?<=^|,)(\d{1,9}|\d{11,})(?=,|$)
```

[RegExr link](https://regexr.com/57k09)

Note: Positive lookbehinds aren't supported by all browsers. [Lookbehind Browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
(\d{10})(,\d{10})*
```